# iOS - Adding Target/Action for UITextField Inside Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have `UITableView` which uses a custom `UITableViewCell` containing a `UITextField`.

I want to call a method (`myMethod`) when it is clicked (`UIControlEventTouchDown`) and attempted to wire this up inside the `UITableView` delegate method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` by doing the following:

```
[tf addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

When the `UITextField` is clicked, nothing happens.

I attempted to do the exact same thing for another `UITextField` outside of the `UITableView`:

```
[othertf addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

When I click on `othertf` the method is called as I would expect.

I'm a bit confused as the code is identical apart from I've swapped `tf` for `othertf`.

Below is the complete code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *DetailCellIdentifier = @"DetailFieldView";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DetailCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *cellObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:DetailCellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (UITableViewCell*) [cellObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    tf.text = @"some value";

    [othertf addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [tf addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    return cell;
}
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? It's probably something simple as I am new to iOS development.

Comment: Does UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:2]; giving you the correct obj? Please check whether its nil or something

Comment: Yes it does as it takes the value assigned on line 11 - `tf.text = @"some value";`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `UITextField` `delegate` Methods:

[UITextField delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

```
//Use this method insted of addTarget:
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField == tf) {
        [self myMethod];
        return NO;
    }

  return YES;
}
```

and dont forget to set the delegate to the textField:

```
 tf.delegate = self;
```

Comment: What is the best way to detect EditingChanged events?

Answer (score 1):

When you touch a UITextField it swallows the touch itself and tells the keyboard to appear etc. Instead use the following events:

```
UIControlEventEditingDidBegin

UIControlEventEditingDidEnd

UIControlEventEditingChanged
```

**Further improvements**

Tags is a rather loose way of coupling your NIB and your code. Consider Making a `DetailCell.h` and `DetailCell.m` file, and set the root view in the NIB file to the DetailCell class, and create reference outlets for all the views you need to access in code, and action outlets for all the actions you need to react on.

[image]

This is done by CTRL clicking on a view in the interface builder, and dragging it into the `DetailCell.h` file. Interface Builder will now ask you wheter you want to create an action or a reference outlet (References are basically pointers, and actions are basically events)

`dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` now calls `initWithFrame` on your DetailCell class every time is creates a new instance of it. It is now your job to load the NIB file in this function.

Alternatively you could register a NIB file for cell reuse on the tableview with

> `[tableview registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:DetailCellIdentifier
>   bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier: DetailCellIdentifier];`

which the automatically loads the nib file every time a new cell is created. In >= iOS 5 (AFAIK) `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` never returns `nil`, but creates instances of the registered classes/nib files itself every time.

Comment: Will this solve the problem or are you just saying you prefer the above approach?