# Delegate method for UITextField not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a tableView cell with a `UITextField` to enter the text.
I am populating the tableView with the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Ingredient Cell";
    IngredientsTableViewCell *ingredientCell = [self.ingredientsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

   // NSManagedObjectContext *managedObject = [self.ingredientItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (ingredientCell == nil)
    {
        ingredientCell = [[IngredientsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        ingredientCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [ingredientCell addSubview:ingredientCell.ingredientTextField];
        [ingredientCell.ingredientTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(editingChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

    }

    //Populate the textfield in the ingredientCell
    ingredientCell.ingredientTextField.text = [self.ingredientItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return ingredientCell;
}
```

Following is the `@selector(editingChanged:)` method for the textField which never executes. What am I doing wrong?

```
-(void) editingChanged:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"hi");

    // get the text being entered
    NSString *ingredientText = ((UITextField *)sender).text;

    //get the index of the selected row
    NSInteger selectedIndex = [self.ingredientsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row;

    //save the text to the array
    [self.ingredientItems setObject:ingredientText atIndexedSubscript:selectedIndex];
}
```

Comment: BTW - `editingChanged:` is not a method of `UITextFieldDelegate`.

Comment: Looks like too much code copying and pasting there. There's something weird happening in that cell creation method. You're instantiating an `IngredientCell` and possibly re-adding one of its subviews to it? You're also adding the subview to the cell instead of its contentView. There's just too much wrong with that code to be able to identify what's going on. Perhaps post your IngredientCell implementation (is this created using a prototype cell in storyboard?). My guess you have 2 textfields in that cell, one is obscuring the other.

Answer (score 0):

So you'll want to use the textFieldDelegate (or if you're adventurous you could use ReactiveCocoa).

Add this at the top

```
<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

And this in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
ingredientCell.ingredientTextField.delegate = self;
ingredientCell.ingredientTextField.tag = 1;
```

And this delegate method

```
//Use this method instead of addTarget:
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField.tag == 1){
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

see this stack overflow post: [iOS - Adding Target/Action for UITextField Inside Custom UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376009/ios-adding-target-action-for-uitextfield-inside-custom-uitableviewcell)

But you might have a slightly different problem as well.  This line of code seems redundant:

```
[ingredientCell addSubview:ingredientCell.ingredientTextField];
```

You're ingredient cell seems like it should already have the ingredientTextField as a subview.  This might cause you problems as well.  You can add it as a subview in a xib that's attached to your ingredientsTableViewCell class, or simply add it in code as

```
[self addSubview:ingredientTextField]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (ingredientCell == nil)
{
    ingredientCell = [[IngredientsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    ingredientCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [ingredientCell addSubview:ingredientCell.ingredientTextField];
    [ingredientCell.ingredientTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(editingChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

}
```

this portion looks much of problems
try taking out this line from if statement

```
[ingredientCell.ingredientTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(editingChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

This will help you.

Comment: How does removing that needed line fix the problem?

Comment: as editingChanged: method is only added as target while cell in nil. Adding it in every cell will fix the problem

Comment: You only want the target added once per cell. Moving it outside the `if` statement will add the target every time the cell is reused. That is not what you want.

Answer (score -2):

You can add this line in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and add `UITextFieldDelegate` in Viewcontroller.h file

```
ingredientCell.ingredientTextField.delegate = self;
[ingredientCell.ingredientTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(editingChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

> This is textfield controller event

```
UIControlEventEditingDidBegin     = 1 << 16,     // UITextField
UIControlEventEditingChanged      = 1 << 17,
UIControlEventEditingDidEnd       = 1 << 18,
UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit = 1 << 19,     // 'return key' ending editing
```

Comment: How does this help? The question is about the `editingChanged:` method not being called. That isn't a delegate method so setting the text field's `delegate` property won't fix it.

Comment: Use this new code this one is perfectly working in my project

Comment: In question, delegate is not set.

Comment: The delegate isn't needed for the control event handler.

Comment: yes,you are right delegate isn't needed for control event handler.But My project editingChanged: method working fine

Comment: ingredientCell = [[IngredientsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] remove this line,this line consider default TableViewCell